# Retrieving the F# code inside a Quotation

Tags: f#, expression-trees, quotations

How can I get the original F# code inside a quotation?

I know that in C# `Expression.ToString()` gives a reasonable string but it's not 100% and doesn't work in F#.

Comment: http://www.fssnip.net/7OG/title/Quotation-Printer

Comment: What is a reasonable string for you? There is the Patterns and DerivedPatterns namespace under `Fsharp.Qutations` with their help you can pattern match on the expression. Take a look at [the Quations doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/code-quotations).

Comment: I'm ultimately looking for something will give me the exact input between <@ @>

Comment: I think the quotation printer quoted above is close, it uses non-light syntax though. I'm no quotation wizard, so not sure if this is possible (e.g. using reflection) or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the library Swensen.Unquote to give satisfactory results.